# Excel- merge string cells with the same prefix

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have few values as below in an excel column.

[image]

If two cells having values like `CalculateZeroValue` and `CalculateZeroValueBusinessArea` both containing same prefix `CalculateZeroValue`, I want to keep only one cell value.

Here's my expected output for the above values.

[image]

I've tried `IF`, `EXACT` and `SEARCH` functions but couldn't achieve the goal. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Just curious, if in row 10 the value is _GetExchangeRate_, row 13 _GetExchange_, row 15 _GetExchangeTomorrow_, row 17 _On Wednesday GetExchangeRate_, row 19 _GetExchange On Monday_, row 21 _blabla GetExchange blublu_, which one to keep ?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear before. I re wrote the question and hope it makes more sense now. I want to keep the shorted common prefix basically.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. So do you mean that there won't be duplicate in the rows of that column? I mean like this : If there is "CalculateZeroValue" in row4 ... there won't be another "CalculateZeroValue" in other row, and if there is "CalculateZeroValueBusinessArea" in row10, there won't be another "CalculateZeroValueBusinessArea" in other row. Please CMIIW.

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Answer (score 0):

If I undertand you correctly, the data before running the sub looks something like this :
[image]

Ignore the color, it's just to show that the the longer text version in each color need to be removed. So the result looks something like this :

[image]

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range, cell As Range, c As Range

With ActiveSheet
Set rg = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
End With

For Each cell In rg
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        Set c = rg.Find(cell.Value, lookat:=xlPart)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                If Len(c) > Len(cell) Then
                    c.ClearContents
                Else
                    Set c = rg.FindNext(c)
                    If Len(c) > Len(cell) Then c.ClearContents
                End If
            End If
    End If
Next

rg.SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

rg variable is the range of data in column A. There must be no blank row in between.

Then it loop to each cell in rg, using the looped cell value to be searched inside the rg as c variable. If c is not nothing, it check if the length of characters of the found cell value (the c variable) is greater then the length of characters of the looped cell value then it clear the content of the found cell (the c variable).

Else, it do a second check by using find-next method. Again it check if the length of characters of the second found cell value (the c variable) is greater then the length of characters of the looped cell value then it clear the content of the found cell (the c variable).

Finally it delete the entire row of the blank cell within rg.